# integrating spring 2.5.6 and Struts 1.3.8

Tags: spring, struts, dispatch, struts-action

I want to clear some moments about integrating spring and struts. I have only one action class per application extended from `MappingDispatchAction`. So, actually my app when doing something uses not Action objects, but methods from my action. All I want from spring is to initialize this action and all for now. Just simply set DAO object. I looked through [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/webintegration.html), but I don't understand following:

We use action path from `struts-config.xml` as a name of bean in action-servlet.xml. Okay, but am I supposed to write beans in `action-servlet.xml` for every path name and set this poor DAO ref or what ?

Comment: Why are you looking at docs for Spring 1.2 if you're using 2.5? Use the [relevant docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/web-integration.html#struts) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Struts 1 config file will use the `DelegatingActionProxy` class as the `type` attribute for all action configurations.

The Spring config file will contain the bean definitions of each action implementation. I don't know what DAO you're talking about, but actions that require DAO or service injection need to have them listed, yes--that's what Spring configuration is.

You may also be able to use annotations if you're not interested in using XML configuration, or use bean inheritance if many beans share the same DAO/service/etc. property values.